# 3 column layout - 1 variable,1 fixed and all equal height - is this code hacky?

Tags: html, css

Long story short is my code hacky?  Being new sometimes the stuff I write "technically works" but I learn later that I used hacks or there were better, more appropriate ways to build something.  I pieced this together from different ideas I found online.

3 Column Layout.

- Left column is 25%
- Right column is 150px
- Middle column uses all remaining space
- All columns should be equal height

So that I'm not wasting anybodies time I validated the CSS on [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net/). Under Windows 10 it worked fine on Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE 8 - 11 and Opera.

[the fiddle for this code](https://jsfiddle.net/hhftz9o8/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="col_left"><p><strong>Left Column Text</strong> Drawings me opinions returned absolute in. Otherwise therefore universal did are unfeeling something. Connection too unaffected expression led son possession. New smiling friends and her another.</p></div>
        <div class="col_right"><p><strong>Right Column Text</strong> Certain be ye amiable by exposed so.</p></div>         
        <div class="col_middle"><p><strong>Middle Column Text</strong> Picture removal detract earnest is by. Esteems met joy attempt way clothes yet demesne tedious. Furnished do otherwise daughters contented conveying attempted no. To sorry world an at do spoil along. Incommode he depending do frankness remainder to. Edward day almost active him friend thirty piqued. People as period twenty my extent as. Set was better abroad ham plenty secure had horses. Admiration has sir decisively excellence say everything inhabiting acceptance. Sooner settle add put you sudden him. Ask especially collecting terminated may son expression. Extremely eagerness principle estimable own was man. Men received far his dashwood subjects new. My sufficient surrounded an companions dispatched in on.</p></div>                     
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 20px auto;  
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden; /* This line is necessary. */
}

.col_left,
.col_middle,
.col_right {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 10px 1000px 10px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px; /* padding 1000 and margin -1000 is the trick to make this work. */
}

.col_left {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgb(220,220,220);
}

.col_middle {
    background-color: rgb(210,210,210);
    overflow: hidden;   /* Not floated left or right so it needs this line to form its own Box Formatting Context. */
}

.col_right {
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200); 
}

p {
    font:100 1em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

.zone_under {
    width: 90%; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    padding: 10px;      
    font: 300 1em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    border: .5em solid rgb(0,0,0);
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's hacky

- `overflow: hidden` as a way to establish a block formatting context is a hack. The proper way is `display: flow-root`, but it's a recent proposal not supported anywhere.
- Using floats for layout can probably be considered a hack
- `padding-bottom: 1000px; margin-bottom: -1000px` is definitely a hack, which you need because you used hacky floats.

The modern way is flexbox:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.col_left {
  width: 25%;
  order: 1;
}
.col_middle {
  flex: 1;
  order: 2;
}
.col_right {
  width: 150px;
  order: 3;
}
```

Comment: Flex looks 100x more sensible than floats.  But on [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) regarding IE 11 and Flex it says, "Partial support is due to large amount of bugs present (see known issues)".  I went to [Stat Counter](http://gs.statcounter.com/) and in the USA IE11 is falling fast but still at 7.47%.  When that piece of junk sinks below 1% I think me and everybody else is going to Flex.  It's so much easier to look at and understand.

Comment: @DR01D are there any pollyfills to get it working in IE11 without everything breaking?

Comment: @Oriol I just tried it in IE11 and IE10 and it worked!  Here is my [Flex Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6oe2ged3/).  I also tried it in an Opera mini emulator and it worked.  So maybe the basic Flex tags work.  As long as I use it for basic layout it's ok... I think. FYI I tried it in IE9 and Flex completely crashed.  None of it works that far back.

Comment: @DR01D IE supports flexbox since version 10. There are some problematic bugs, but basic layouts like this should work indeed. See [Flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs)

Comment: @Oriol is there a Flex "basics/how-to" page that you respect?  If I use Flex I won't have to flush the other HTML tags I've learned?

Comment: I just checked [Stat Counter](http://gs.statcounter.com/) again and in the USA 12 months ago IE8 was at 1.89% and today it is at 0.41%.  12 months ago IE9 was at 1.46% and today it is at 0.35%.  They're both gonners.  I guess that means it is the end of the line for old layout methods, HTML5 Shiv and Modernizr too.

Comment: This just went into my favorites. [flexplorer](http://bennettfeely.com/flexplorer/).

Answer (score 2):

Yep, looks hacky to me.
Doesn't look great from a responsive design point of view.
Having the padding at 1000px might work at one screen resolution, but we have many screen sizes to consider. A better approach would be as below.

```
.wrapper {
        margin: 20px auto;  
        width: 90%;
        position:relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .col_left,
    .col_middle,
    .col_right {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .col_left {
        width: 25%;
        background-color: rgb(220,220,220);
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
    }

    .col_middle {
        width: auto;
        background-color: rgb(210,210,210);
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left: 25%;
        bottom:0;
        right: 150px;
    }

    .col_right {
        width: 150px;
        background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
    }
```

If you resize your browser you will notice it adapts to the screen size.

Then you could use media queries to make it look good for mobiles and tablets. i.e.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .col_left {
            width: 100%;
            height:auto;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            bottom: auto;
            top:0;
            position:relative;
        }
        .col_middle {
            width: 100%;
            height:auto;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            bottom: auto;
            top:0;
            position:relative;
        }
        .col_right {
            width: 100%;
            height:auto;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            bottom: auto;
            top:0;
            position:relative;
        }
    }
```

I would recommend looking at Bootstrap's grid layout.

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

And if all you want is the grid layout from bootstrap and no other features of functionality, you can use the bootstrap customizer to reduce file sizes.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Simply uncheck all checkboxes and leave the grid system checked under common css and download.
Makes life much easier than coming up with hacks.

Comment: `padding: 10px 10px 1000px 10px;` and `margin-bottom: -1000px;` are according to Oriol (and I believe him) hacks.  But they don't impact screen height.  If you check [the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhftz9o8/) everything below the text disappears.  I'm going to try the code you uploaded right now.  Also unfortunately I can't use bootstrap.  Google's new [AMP Project](https://www.ampproject.org/) doesn't allow user written Javascript.  Basically no JS except what they provide.  Plus I'm trying to learn HTML/CSS from the ground up so I like programming it without a framework.

Comment: Ahh yep different result using fiddle. when I put your code into notepad++ and run in the browser I get a different result.

Comment: I guess it depends on what your trying to acheive. having 1000px padding at the bottom and -1000px margin at the bottom would be better to have `padding: 10px;` and `margin-bottom: 0;`